# How can I automate creation of TFS Test Case's for each C# TestMethod Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, automated-tests, requirements

I'm using **TFS** 2010, **VS2010** and **C#**.  I need to link each requirement to the unit test or tests associated with that requirement.  I've found that in order to link Tests to requirements, TFS requires a Test Case for each **[TestMethod]** unit test.  Only then can I link the *Requirement* to the *Test Case* which in turn is associated with the automated unit test.  I'm looking for a way to shortcut this so that Test Cases can be created automatically for all exiting Tests.  Ideally the TFS Test Case description would come from the **[TestMethod]** header comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to create a couple of test cases, you can do it directly from Visual Studio by opening the Test Window, select your test, right-click and choose "Create Test Case From Test". You must have your test projects opened in order to see your automated tests in the Test Window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx#NewTestCase

If you want to import a bunch of automated tests from a test assembly, you can use the command-line tool for Test Management, called tcm.exe (you can find it under Common7\IDE\ of your Visual Studio location). The following command will do the trick:

tcm testcase /import /storage:[test assembly] /collection:[url] /teamproject:[your team project]

You can also specify the categories or the priorities of tests you want to import. For more information, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465191.aspx#CreateTestCases

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.  I could wish that multiple selection didn't gray out the _Create Test Case From Test_  menu item, so it could be done from Visual Studio instead of command line.